# survey question at the end of the posts

Tags: discussion

When i open any post on the site without actually logging in, at the end of the post there is a survey question "Was this post useful to you ?" with an yes/no type of choice to answer. I wonder what happens when we click on yes/no. Is this data displayed anywhere, and what is it used for ?

Answer (score 7):

See these threads on meta.SO:

- [Anonymous user feedback now in testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing)
- [What should we do with anonymous user feedback?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99370/what-should-we-do-with-anonymous-user-feedback)

explaining that there is not much to it at the moment, but there might be in the future. At the moment the anonymous feedback is just collected.

---

Users with more than 10k reputation can explore the stats [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback). I don't know if these or similar statistics are visible to users with lower reputation.

---

**Added:** (April 9, 2012)

[A meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3931/5363) by [draks](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19341/draks) pointed out that the anonymous user feedback can be queried on [data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/queries):

- [Feedback on my posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts)
- [Negative feedback on my posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/62474/negative-feedback-on-my-posts)
- [Feedback for a specific post](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/61534/feedback-for-a-specific-post)

for example (I haven't tested them).

Comment: It is not visible to me (8,497 rep).

Comment: I suspected that because it is under `/tools` which is accessible only after passing the magic 10k mark. Perhaps I should have said "[...] if these [...] statistics are visible *elsewhere* [...]"