# Was this post useful to you?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [survey question at the end of the posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824/survey-question-at-the-end-of-the-posts)

I don't browse M.SE without being looged in. 
Therefore I, just by chance, I found a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/60678/negative-feedback-on-my-posts) that tells you something about the feedback that un-registered users give.

What is it for?

Comment: @t.b. Cool thanks, should I delete this one?

Comment: As you wish. You could also leave it, because there's no harm and the worst that can (and probably will) happen is that it gets closed. Maybe it helps others find the relevant thread.

Comment: @Draks The query link is useful, so if you delete this question then please add the query link to the other question.

Comment: @Bill: I have just added the three relevant queries to the answer to the other question.